# Delphi XE7 IDE replaces my text as I type

Tags: delphi, ide

Hi guys I have a big problem

Somehow I must have set the Delphi XE7 IDE to replace my next text as I type for example:

if I have typed `StToInt` into the IDE (Which is obviously wrong), then put my curser after the first `t` and then press `r` the IDE will now show `StroInt` (replaces the `T` with the `r`) an not `StrToInt`

it does this with all my text

How do I set this back to normal?

Please help, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Ins</kbd> key on your keyboard to toggle between insert and overwrite mode.

Note that the status bar at the bottom of the IDE editor window displays either *Insert* or *Overwrite* depending which mode is currently active.

Comment: Worth noting that this used to be common in text and word processors in earlier times.  Wordpad still behaves this way but MS Word disabled the `Ins` key overwrite toggle in 2007 (it's still an option).  It originally existed for typists migrating from typewriters, which naturally behave this way.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I can't believe it was something so small... I will select as answer when I am able. Bless you man

Comment: Such a cute question!